# Поиск словосочетания в строке Python

Tags: python, search

Есть текст из него нужно найти Фамилии и инициалы. В строке могут быть 1 или несколько фамилий.
Пример: "(лек)Название пары Петров А.А. ауд. 12 <-----> (пр)Название пары Рыбин О.А. ауд. 15"
Вывод: "Петров А.А." "Рыбин О.А."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простейшее регулярное выражение вам поможет:

```
import re

text = "(лек)Название пары Петров А.А. ауд. 12 <-----> (пр)Название пары Рыбин О.А. ауд. 15"
rx = re.compile(r'\w+\s+\w\.\w\.')
print(rx.findall(text))
```

Вывод:

```
['Петров А.А.', 'Рыбин О.А.']
```

Я тут даже не проверяю большие или маленькие буквы, у меня просто проверяется наличие строки формата:

```
\w+ строка из букв
\s+ пробел(ы)
\w  буква
\.  точка
\w  буква
\.  точка
```

Если нужно вы уж дальше как-то сами доделывайте.